# Error: write EPIPE on Cloud Run while using html-pdf NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Here I was trying to convert HTML to PDF and used html-pdf npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf)). The code was running fine on local and got an issue over google cloud run.

```
Error: write EPIPE at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:154:25) at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:145:3) at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:786:11) at Socket._write (net.js:798:8) at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403:12) at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5) at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11) at PDF.PdfExec [as exec] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/html-pdf/lib/pdf.js:141:15) at PDF.PdfToBuffer [as toBuffer] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/html-pdf/lib/pdf.js:44:8) at utilities.createPDF (/usr/src/app/routes/lib/utilities.js:810:31)

Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:

 at errorOrDestroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:108:12)

 at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:418:5)

 at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:445:5)

 at internal/streams/destroy.js:50:7

 at Socket._destroy (net.js:679:5)

 at Socket.destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:38:8)

 at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:154:17)

 at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:145:3)

 at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:786:11)

 at Socket._write (net.js:798:8) {

 errno: 'EPIPE',

 code: 'EPIPE',

 syscall: 'write'
```

This the JS code used, error occurred on *pdf.create* function:-

```
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var html = <HTML code>;
var options = { 
    format: 'A4',
    border: {
        "top": "20px",            
        "right": "15px",
        "bottom": "15px",
        "left": "12.5px"
      },
 };
 
pdf.create(html, options).toBuffer(function(err, buffer){
  console.log('This is a buffer:', Buffer.isBuffer(buffer));
    console.log(buffer);
```

Comment: I think I have read somewhere that socket creation wasn't authorized. However, I'm not sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a discussion with NPM creator and discussed that npm uses socket programming in it.
So on further research found the Cloud Run doesn't support internal Socket calling, which is the correct reason this is not working.

Comment: ive got same issue. did you find an alternative approach / lib ?

Comment: @ajonno I have used the GCP VM for deploying my application which solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Cloud Run [does not support HTML streaming](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues#grpc_websocket), which is what I interpret the code to be doing in the error message, so it looks like that specific code might not be supported.

Comment: This link helped.

Comment: That's great! It would be beneficial to the community if you mark my answer as accepted so the community can find it easier